# Java Interface - Object to class typecasting

Tags: java, object, interface

I have an interface that looks something like

public interface KeyRetriever {

```
public Object getKey(Object obj);
```

}

I want the implementation to be something like

CustomerTypeKeyRetriever (Implementation class)

```
public String getKey(Customer customer) {
    return null;
}
```

How can I achieve this. Currently it throws a compilation error - "The type CustomerTypeKeyRetriever must implement the inherited abstract method  KeyRetriever.getKey(Object)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation should have method like

```
@Override
    public Object getKey(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

I would also put a @Override annotation to on all my implementaion method so that compiler can catch any method changes/conflicts in future in case API's change.

In case you want generified interface, below should work (this is what i think you might want)

```
public interface KeyRetriever<T> {
    public Object getKey(T obj);
}

public class CustomerTypeKeyRetriever implements KeyRetriever<Customer> {

    @Override
    public String getKey(Customer obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here the return type can be any subclass of Object since java supports [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) return types.

Comment: Thank You Santosh and GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR. The solution worked :)

Answer (score 4):

use generics in your interface declaration.

```
public interface KeyRetriever<T> {

public Object getKey(T obj);
}
```

now in your subclass you can implement it

```
 public class CustomerTypeKeyRetriever implements KeyRetriever<String> {
  public String getKey(String str){
        //your implementation

  }
 }
```

Comment: +1 nice idea - return type should probably be Object in this case, or a `KeyRetriever<S, T>` maybe...

Comment: Thank You.. This is exactly what I was looking for.. Could you please shed some light on how this actually works.

Comment: I agree with @assylias. In the example, both the return type and the param's type are the same. Indeed, `getKey` would be defined as you suggest but the OP seeks to return different types (`String` when passing a `Customer`).

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a Person interface :

```
public interface Person {}
```

Your Customer and Employee classes implemented that :

```
public class Customer implements Person {/* Your class body */}
public class Employee implements Person {/* Your class body */}
```

Then you can change your interface like this :

```
public interface KeyRetriever {

public String getKey(Person person);
}
```

And in your Customer class you then have to change like this :

```
public String getKey(Person perosn) {
   return null;
}
```

Hope that helps . Happy coding :)